# Create customs template components Sencha Architect 2

Tags: extjs4, extjs, sencha-architect

How can I create a customs template for my component.
Has anyone used the Sencha Architect 2 ?

I found import of unknown XDC file only, but I do not have, and how to create do not know.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the Sencha Architect, go to Project Inspector and drag a CSS Resource to the Resources section under Application. Then enter your url for the css file, relative to the app folder, eg ../_styles/myCSS.css and give it an id so that it looks nice under Resources, eg myCSS.

But remember that Architect runs with metadata, so you actually need to add your css code into the "Code" block in Sencha Architect so that it is applied.

Comment: It seems like I overwrote someone's comment and I didn't mean to do that. Something went wrong whilst I was editing and I thought that I was editing something I had already added.